# Regex tokenizing with Boost only getting last letters of words

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize, boost-regex

I am trying to parse a simple sentence structure with Boost. This is my first time using Boost, so I could be doing this completely wrong.  What I want to do is only accept strings in this format:

- Must start with a letter (case insensitive)
- May contain:

  - Alphabetic characters
  - Numeric characters
  - Underscores
  - Hyphens
- All other characters serve as delimiters

Since I don't know what characters are my delimiters (there could be tons), I have tried to make a regex that is sensitive to that.  The only problem is, I am only getting the last letter of each word.  This leads me to believe that my regex is correct, but my use of boost is not.  Here's my code:

```
boost::regex regexp("[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_|-)*", boost::regex::normal | boost::regbase::icase);
boost::sregex_token_iterator i(text.begin(), text.end(), regexp, 1);
boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
while(i != j){
    cout << *i++ << std::endl;
}
```

I modeled this after what I found on the [Boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html).  I used the last example (at the bottom of the page) as a template to build mf code.  In this instance, text is an object of type string.

Is my regex correct?  Am I using boost correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to: `([A-Za-z][-A-Za-z0-9_]*)`

By putting the parentheses around the whole expression, the entire thing will be captured, not just the last character matched. Putting the - in front causes it to be a matched character and not a range specifier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! I removed the trailing * because I don't want 0-length words.

Comment: You definitely want the trailing *. Without it, the regex will only match two character words. No need to worry about zero length words. The initial [A-Za-z] must match exactly one character.

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting the first submatch for each RE match. That refers to this subexpression: `([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_|-)` and you're getting the last thing that matched (notice that it's qualified by a `*`) for each match. Hence, the last character. I think you should pass 0 for the submatch number, or just omit that parameter. When I modify your code to do that, it does what I think you're wanting it to do.

Comment: I tried using 0 for the submatch number, but that didn't fix it.  While your answer was technically correct, I went with Ferruccio because it was simpler.  Thanks though! I wish I could have two correct answers!!

Comment: Well, you could always upvote both of us :-). (Using 0 for the submatch number definitely seems to do the job for me; I wonder why it doesn't for you.)

Comment: There, I upvoted both of you.  I'm not sure what it was, but it works now.  I'm sure I had some weird type-o that was fixed by Ferruccio.  But when I just used 0, I got even less (only single characters that were not in my regex like whitespace and periods).